# latency on hadoop hybrid cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, hadoop, cloud

I have seen an architecture of Hybrid HADOOP cluster with some nodes on premise and some others on cloud. as data will move between both of the systems, does this kind of architecture as latency killer ?

same question for a full cloud hadoop cluster, as the hosts are not geographicaly in the same location, will this impact the performance/latency ?

thanks in advance

Comment: You're typically not mirroring whole datasets. Only parts that are relevant to those regions/providers. For example, running BigQuery vs Athena

Comment: actually it wasn't a mirroring solution, it's was more about having datanodes from both cloud and on premise under the same namenode namespace

Comment: Typically you wouldn't have datanodes in the cloud. You would use the respective object store of that provider. S3 & Azure Blob store, for example. But that of course adds latency itself as a object store rather than a block store

Comment: Exactly, that was my first remark hence my question on stackoverflow. their architecture is as bellow 4 datanodes on premise, and 12 on cloud with one default hadoop rack.

Comment: You typically would setup HDFS Federation for something like this, or at least set the rack properties differently for the other data center. I've heard of set-ups like one replica is local, and two are remote, but I don't know if that can be guaranteed. Meanwhile, other architectures ditch Hadoop completely because their data model is known well ahead of time, so it's stored in Cassandra, which has good multi region support

Comment: Yes I'm agree about what you are saying ( HDFS Federation and Rack strategy ).